# sailsのインストール中にエラーが出ます。

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

node jsを利用しています。
npm？でSailsをインストールしようとしているのですが、必ずこのエラーが発生してしまいます。
何がダメなのでしょうか？

```
C:\Users\ユーザー名\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\socket.io\node
_
modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj(44,46): error
 MSB4025: プロジェクト ファイルを読み込めませんでした。指定されたエンコードに無
効な文字があります。 行 44、位置 46。
```

Comment: sails.jsのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\src> npm install -g socket.io
```

で出るなら、原因はユーザー名が non-ascii だと出る問題のような気がします。

[Installing on Windows 8.1 with umlauts in the path #1676](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1676)

(ちょっと確実な回避方法を示すことができんです、すみません。。)